# Spring Security OAuth 2.0 Google: redirect to default URL after unauthorized request instead of requested URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-kotlin

I'm using Spring Security OAuth 2.0 with Google as identity provider. I have problem with proper handling of session timeout and reauthentication.

Scenario:

- Some request to REST API after session timeout.
- Frontend handles HTTP 403 and shows screen with link to Spring Security login endpoint.
- User clicks on this link. Spring issues redirect to Google login page with necessary parameters (code, state, etc.). User successfully reauthenticates.

Current behaviour:

- After login Google redirects to previously requested REST API URL. As a result user sees some JSON in browser. I simply don't understand what part of application could have been saved it. I disabled everything. (See comments below configuration class.)

Desired behaviour:

- After login Google redirects to some starting UI screen.

My configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Value("\${app.security.oauth2.defaultSuccessUrl}")
    lateinit var defaultSuccessUrl: String

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity) {
        val successHandler = SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
        successHandler.setUseReferer(false)
        httpSecurity
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/js/**", "/error**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2Login()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .defaultSuccessUrl(defaultSuccessUrl)
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
    }

}
```

- `defaultSuccessUrl` is set to the desired UI screen.
- I've already changed success handler to `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead of `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to turn off saving requested URL by Spring.
- `successHandler.setUseReferer(false)` to disable `Referer` header on HTTP level.
- I'm using `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint()` to just issue HTTP 403 on session timeout. Frontend handles this and shows login screen with link to Spring Security login URL.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

UPD: Updated code according to answer by [Steve Riesenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15835039/steve-riesenberg):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Value("\${app.security.oauth2.defaultSuccessUrl}")
    lateinit var defaultSuccessUrl: String

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity) {
        val successHandler = SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(defaultSuccessUrl)
        successHandler.setUseReferer(false)
        httpSecurity
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/js/**", "/error**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2Login()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `defaultSuccessUrl` will override your `successHandler()`, as setting the URL actually adds `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` that you wanted to replace. Order matters, as there is only one `successHandler` in the `oauth2Login` configurer.

Instead, you will want to pass the `defaultSuccessUrl` to the constructor of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, and only set the `successHandler(successHandler)`.